# Zend Framework 2 recursive queries cause memory leaks

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework, recursion, memory-leaks, zend-framework2

My ZF2 application, to retrieve some information, calls recursively a function which queries the Postgresql database. This recursive calling sometimes causes the script to run out of memory.
Before and after the recursive call I run the memory_get_usage() function and I noticed that after the database recursive queries the memory used by the script has increased.

I was wondering what causes this memory increase and what should I do to reduce and/or to avoid this memory allocation.

This is the flow of the process:

```
public function getInfoAction()
{
    // this call returns about 8000 items
    $items = $this->getServiceLocator->get("Application/Model/ItemsTable")->getItems();
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $memory = memory_get_usage();
        $item->recursiveGetInfo();
        $memory = memory_get_usage();
    }
}
```

This is the *recursiveGetInfo* function:

```
function recursiveGetInfo()
{
    if(isset($this->info))
        return $this->info;

    if(!$this->isSingleItems())
        $this->info = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("Application/Model/InfoTable")->fetchRow($this->code);
    else
    {
        foreach($this->getSingleItems() as $items)
        {
            $this->info = $items->recursiveGetInfo();
        }
    }
    return $this->info;
}
```

And this is the *fetchRow* function of the *InfoTable* classes:

```
public function fetchRow($code)
{
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(array('code' => $code));
    return $resultSet->current();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a memory leak rather than just normal memory usage? Do you keep result-sets from each query?

Comment: Calling the recursive function leads the script to run out of memory when many recursive calls happen area performed. 
I tried not to keep the result-sets and unset them but the usage of the memory is still the same. I was wondering if this is due to something regarding querying the database.

Comment: Who can tell? You haven't supplied any example code. I'd suspect the result sets are being kept around, but there's no way to tell.

Comment: Ok, I added the code to be more clear.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand the code. Would I be right in thinking the first two code fragments are from different classes? I don't quite understand the logic in the repeated queries either - it seems horribly inefficient. In any case, memory usage will obviously increase due to the new data being added to your structure. So - why do you suspect a leak, and is garbage collection enabled on your installation?

Comment: sorry I didn't explained it. The first fragment of the code is from the controller, the second fragment is from the Item class. An Item instance can be composed by other Item instances, that is why the function check if the item is composed by multiple items (and if it is true runs for each item the function recursiveGetInfo). I hope to have been clear.

Comment: But you're overwriting $this->info inside the loop (except it'll already be set so it will keep the same value) so why bother with the loop? Anyway - you still need to answer the question: why do you think there is a memory leak?